# Can I delete my downvoted question that is on the wrong Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, off-topic, vote-to-delete

I am a new user and I had no idea how many Stack Exchage sites existed. I wanted to ask a designing related question and I asked it on Stack Overflow main website which later on I came to know was not the correct site to ask. Then I was given a link to all prevalent Stack Exchange site and so I asked my question on the Graphics and designing related site.

But because I asked it first on the wrong website somebody downvoted me. Now if I delete my question then will I be banned from asking questions as the question was downvoted. It might create an impression that I deleted it because it was downvoted. Also, why downvote somebody who already has agreed to delete the question from the wrong place and ask it on a correct place. I mean I lost my 2 reputation points because of that. Below is the url to my question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295256/text-revolving-around-planet-effect-photoshop

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I tried doing that and it says that I can delete it after 2 days due to possible opening. I will try to delete after 2 days.. Thanks again for your reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to delete your own question if it gets closed. You can also get your 2 rep back if you do. Go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and click on the button at the end to trigger a reputation recalc after you delete your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can always flag the question for moderator attention, explain your case, and it will be solved if appropriate within seconds (depending on the site). *solved* meaning that a moderator can delete your question without having to wait 2 days.

Keep in mind that you won't get the reputation back immediately, but you can force a recalc by going to [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and clicking "Trigger Reputation Recalc" at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you posted on the wrong site, you shouldn't be deleting your question. Flag it for moderator attention asking them to migrate it to the correct site for you.

Comment: True, but sadly it was downvoted which means there is less incentive to do so.